# VBA excel searching columns and rows then insert to that cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in VBA excel, now I require to develop a Marco to search through a table and insert the value to that particular cell. I know there is a technique which to loop through all the column and row,  but it create more problems to my code. Any other technique can achieve that?

Suppose I have a table:
[image]

How can I search for Week 7 and Bread and I want to insert value of 10 in that cell in Marco? Thank you.

Comment: You want to loop through the values in column A until you find a match, that is your row number, loop through row 1 until you match Week 7, that is your column number, then just write to the cell

    ActiveSheet.Range(rownum, colnum).value = 10

Comment: Yes, I know that, but any function that already available in VBA for searching, besides the looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a loop you can get the target row and columns by using .Find() to get the row ans column numbers and then Cells (rownumber, columnnumber) to store the data.

The code below should give you a way forward

```
Sub insert()
Dim myColumn As Range
Dim myRow As Range

Set myColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("2:2").Find("Week 2")
Set myRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Find("Nuts")

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(myRow.Row, myColumn.Column) = "10"
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks, may I know what "2:2" and "A:A" refer to?

Comment: 2:2 of the second row of the sheet, where your Week numbers are and "A:A" is column "A". Sorry I should have been clearer.

Comment: Thanks, it should be "1:1" right since my weeks are on first row, right?